# Marklogic - What is the best way to loop throught 10 thousand documents if you know id

Tags: marklogic

I have a list more than ten thousand ids need to retrieve XML data if they are matched.  What is a best solution to approach this.  I think my code is not the right way to loop through a $listKeyID. Please help.  Thanks in advance.

```
let $listKeyID := ("accid01","accid02",......"accid100000") (: a huge list :)
let $uris := cts:uris((),
                      (),
                     cts:and-query((                          
                           cts:collection-query("/collection/TRIS"),
                           cts:or-query((
                           cts:field-word-query("key",($listKeyID))
                           ))
                     ))
                 )
             )
 return fn:count($uris)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is not that much wrong with this approach. `cts:field-word-query` accepts a sequence as second argument, and will return positive for any match within that sequence. We also refer to that as a shotgun-OR query, and it is pretty efficient.

You don't really need the extra `cts:or-query` around it though, and you might want to use a `cts:field-value-query` instead, which matches the entire key value, instead of mid-sentence tokens, depending on your use case.

```
let $listKeyIDs := (accid01,accid02,......accid100000) (: a huge list :)
let $uris := cts:uris(
    (),
    (),
    cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query("/collection/TRIS"),
        cts:field-value-query("key", $listKeyIDs)
    ))
)
return fn:count($uris)
```

HTH!

Comment: Can Marklogic read a text file contains all IDs, then loop through each id in text file.  Thanks

Comment: You can use http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:filesystem-file , but bear in mind that has to be at a path that the MarkLogic server can see.

Comment: Remember that calling cts:uris is ok for sample code here but in reality you would want to act on the nodes not on the URIs, by for example running a cts:search and processing the resultant nodes.

Comment: It works use tokenize function.  Thanks for all your helping.
let $listID := xdmp:filesystem-file("/output/listID.txt")
let $tokenizekey := tokenize($listID,"\n")                (: want tokenize by a new line \n :)

let $uris := cts:uris(
                      (),
                        (),
    cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query("/collection/TRIS"),
        cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("meta:key"),($tokenizekey))
    ))
)
return fn:count($uris)